# Android Studio erro interno barra de rolagem

Tags: android-studio

uso Debian 8 com KDE e Android Studio última versão, no primeiro projeto notei ao rolar a barra na janela das propriedades ou da paleta de ferramentas a tela não é atualizada. Tanto faz rolar agarrando na barra ou com a rodinha do mouse. Acontece somente no Android Studio, outros programas não. Alguém teve esse erro e conseguiu resolver?